# jscape sftp Exception com.jscape.inet.sftp.SftpException caused by java.io.IOException

Tags: java, client, sftp

I tried sftp program to download a file using sftp protocol and used following code,
with the help of this code I tried to download a file using SSH ftp.

I downloaded required jscape jar files and added to the build path. It works correctly. Once I executed I got `runtime >errors`

```
    import com.jscape.inet.sftp.Sftp;
    import com.jscape.inet.sftp.SftpException;
    import com.jscape.inet.sftp.events.SftpAdapter;
    import com.jscape.inet.sftp.events.SftpDownloadEvent;
    import com.jscape.inet.sftp.events.SftpConnectedEvent;
    import com.jscape.inet.sftp.events.SftpDisconnectedEvent;
    import com.jscape.inet.ssh.util.SshParameters;

    public class sftpDownload extends SftpAdapter {

       // perform multiple file download
       public void doDownload(String sftpHostname, String sftpUsername, String sftpPassword, String filter) 
          throws SftpException 
       {
          // create/initialize an Sftp instance
          SshParameters params = new SshParameters(sftpHostname, sftpUsername, sftpPassword);           
          Sftp ftp = new Sftp(params);

          //capture FTP related events when applicable (if your class extends SftpAdapter or implements FtpListener)
          ftp.addSftpListener(this);

          // establish connection
          if(ftp.isConnected())
          {
              System.out.println("Connected");
              ftp.disconnect();
              //ftp.getFilePermissions(null);
          }
          else
          {
          ftp.connect();
          }

        //  ftp.connect();        

          // download files matching  filter
          ftp.mdownload(filter);

          // disconnect
          ftp.disconnect();
       }    

       // captures download event
       public void download(SftpDownloadEvent evt) {
          System.out.println("Downloaded file: " + evt.getFilename());
       }

       // captures connect event
       public void connected(SftpConnectedEvent evt) {
          System.out.println("Connected to server: " + evt.getHostname());
       }

       // captures disconnect event
       public void disconnected(SftpDisconnectedEvent evt) {
          System.out.println("Disconnected from server: " + evt.getHostname());
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          try {
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
             System.out.print("Enter SFTP hostname : ");
             String sftpHostname = reader.readLine().trim();
             System.out.print("Enter SFTP username : ");
             String sftpUsername = reader.readLine().trim();
             System.out.print("Enter SFTP password : ");
             String sftpPassword = reader.readLine().trim();
             System.out.print("Enter download filter (eg .*\\.csv): ");
             String filter = reader.readLine().trim();            

             sftpDownload load=new sftpDownload();

             // do download
             load.doDownload(sftpHostname, sftpUsername, sftpPassword, filter);

          }
          catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             // e.getMessage();
          }
       }
    }
```

and once I gave the Hostname,username, password, filter, I got

```
    com.jscape.inet.sftp.SftpException
       at com.jscape.inet.sftp.SftpConfiguration.createClient(Unknown Source)
    at com.jscape.inet.sftp.Sftp.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.jscape.inet.sftp.Sftp.connect(Unknown Source)

 and 
     Caused by: java.io.IOException  '
```

Please help me to work the above sftp code , Thanks in advance

The following information is my input page,here only I passing host name and other information's >type of file to be downloaded and etc., Please clarify me for SFTP type code firewall settings are need to change?? If so please tell the steps...

```
    Enter SFTP hostname : *.*.*.*
    Enter SFTP username : *******
    Enter SFTP password : password
    Enter download filter (eg .*\.csv): *\.csv
    com.jscape.inet.sftp.SftpException
    at com.jscape.inet.sftp.SftpConfiguration.createClient(Unknown Source)
    at com.jscape.inet.sftp.Sftp.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.jscape.inet.sftp.Sftp.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.file.sftpDownload.doDownload(sftpDownload.java:36)
    at com.test.file.sftpDownload.main(sftpDownload.java:78)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at com.jscape.inet.util.n.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.jscape.inet.util.n.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.jscape.inet.util.n.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.jscape.inet.util.ConnectionParameters.createPlainSocket(Unknown Source)
    at com.jscape.inet.util.ConnectionParameters.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at com.jscape.inet.ssh.transport.TransportClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.jscape.inet.ssh.SshConfiguration.createConnectionClient(Unknown Source)
    at com.jscape.inet.ssh.SshStandaloneConnector.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Look http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/37565-jsch-secure-file-transfer-protocol-sftp.html for more...

Comment: Please provide the entire exception trace, and please format it as another code snippet.

Comment: @Rakesh your code not responding or giving no response sir

Comment: @Kenster please see the exception trace

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that JScape is having a problem converting the SFTP hostname that you provided into an IP address.

Comment: @Kenster thank you , how to correct the problem?